# the program ignores second loop

Tags: c++

my program ignores second loop and I can't fill vector v2

```
            vector<int> v1;
    vector<int> v2;
    int elem1,elem2;

    cout<<"Insert v1: ";
    while(cin>>elem1){
        v1.push_back(elem1);
    }

    cout<<"Insert v2: ";
    while(cin>>elem2){
        v2.push_back(elem2);
    }
```

Comment: The first loop already captures any input from `cin` such that there is nothing left for your second loop. What do you try to accomplish?

Comment: would be more better , if you also ask the user to input y or n char for input at end , according to which you continue with looping until user enters y or break if n;

Answer (score 5):

cin keeps going until all output is done, your 2nd loop is never gonna get hit unless you break from your first loop somehow. I would recommend you have some sort of exit condition on the first loop (such as some input marker like 'DONE' or something and once you read that you should break).

Comment: You can read past EOF. Just clear the eofbit and reset the file position. If std::cin is tied to a terminal, this enables one to use EOF as the input marker you are talking about. See my answer. Note that my answer won't work if std::cin is reading from a file or a pipeline.

Comment: You are correct but for simplicity's sake (and since I don't know exactly what he's doing) I was thinking he wanted to read some elements into v1 then read a marker and then read into v2 or something along those lines.

Comment: That's what I was assuming he wants as well. EOF can make for a nice marker **if** the input stream is known to be tied to the terminal. No parsing is needed. Just reset and voila! next batch of stuff is ready to read.

Comment: That's valid, not usually what I tend to see as EOF should just mean EOF but it works

Comment: EOF does not always mean that the end has come. Have you ever used `tail -f` ?

Comment: It just seems odd to me to use EOF as a marker in input to signal end of reading input set 1 and move on to input set 2 which is past EOF

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you were expecting the first loop to end when you hit enter or something. but that's not what you coded. You coded 'fill up v1 until there is no input left', so it's not surprising that nothing ever gets put in v2.

Perhaps you could try the following, this reads one line, and put the contents in v1, it then reads a second line and puts the contents in v2. It uses getline to read a single line of text, then put that line into a string stream where you can read from one number at a time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void fill_vector_from_one_line(vector<int>& v)
{
    string str;
    if (getline(cin, str))
    {
        istringstream iss(str);
        int elem;
        while (iss >> elem)
            v.push_back(elem);
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Insert v1: ";
    fill_vector_from_one_line(v1);
    cout << "Insert v2: ";
    fill_vector_from_one_line(v2);
}
```

Apologies for any errors, I haven't checked this.

Answer (score 0):

Reset standard input. See below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> v1;
   std::vector<int> v2;
   int elem;

   std::cout << "Insert v1: ";
   while (std::cin >> elem) {
      v1.push_back (elem);
   }

   // Reset std::cin.
   std::cin.clear();
   std::cin.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

   std::cout << "Insert v2: ";
   while (std::cin >> elem) {
      v2.push_back (elem);
   }

   // Just to show that it works.
   std::cout << "\nv1 elements:\n";
   for (unsigned int ii = 0; ii < v1.size(); ++ii) {
      std::cout << "v1[" << ii << "] = " << v1[ii] << "\n";
   }

   std::cout << "\nv2 elements:\n";
   for (unsigned int ii = 0; ii < v2.size(); ++ii) {
      std::cout << "v2[" << ii << "] = " << v2[ii] << "\n";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Note that the `std::cin.clear(); std:cin.seekg();` calls will have different behaviors depending on the nature of std::cin.

- If std::cin is tied to the terminal it will have exactly the behavior that the OP is seeking.
- If std::cin is reading from a file, vector v2 will be a carbon copy of vector v1.
- If std::cin is reading from a pipe, vector v2 will be empty. You can't seekg() on a pipeline.